# Unable to communicate between two MDS simulator

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

I want to chat between two MDS simulator. First i run the run.bat file and then after installing BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 6.0.0, i start sim1.bat and sim2.bat. Then when i am sending the invitation from simulator 1 to simulator 2 by pin 2100000B, invitation is not going to the second simulator. How i can solve this problem??

I am working in windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Download BBM configuration pdf from [this URL](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/36641/)

Read carefully `Chapter 5,6 & 7` and follow the instruction . it will max 1 hour take your time to conufigure that.

After successfully configured in your system. Follow the below step .

1. Start sim1.bat and run.bat from your MDS folder for simulator1.
2. Start sim2.bat and run.bat from your MDS folder for simulator2.
   Both run.bar file connect to each other Simulator ..than Send request from simulator1 to simulator2.

U will get notification in Simulator2 than accept it  .. it will work in this way .
i hope it should be work in your case.